# Move window back from out of the screen

Tags: window-manager

Occasionally I got window showing only left lower corner on the screen. Other parts are out of the screen. Window header is out of the screen.

Is it possible to bring it back?

On Windows I would try to initiate window dragging by keyboard, but what to do on MacOS?

---

I have several monitors which I am connecting and disconnecting from time to time. Sometimes this leads to described situation.

I would like general solution. Suppose I have 2 monitors connected, but only one is physically accessible. Suppose window is on montor 2 and I am on monitor 1. Can I bring window to monitor 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the position of the window you can use the commands in the menubar to get the window back on the screen (in most cases).

1. Make sure that the application of the off-screen window is in focus. You can use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate to the app and focus it.
2. In the menubar go to Window → Zoom (second option of that menu)

   [image]

The off-screen window should now move onto the screen.

Comment: Just tried for arbitrary program but it didn't work. I have `LibreOffice` on screen 2 and tried to reach it from screen 1. I did CMD-TAB and switched to `LibreOffice`, but this had effect only on screen 2. On screen 1 menu was fro another application (Chrome). Pressing Zoom had no effect.

Comment: I understood "out of the screen" as not visible on any screen (neither 1 or 2). In case there is only one screen, are you able to CMD-TAB to LibreOffice?

Comment: Imagine I have 10 monitors. Should I manually search for window on one of them? I am the user and I need my window. I don't know where is it. I am on montor X, my mouse is on monitor X. How to bring window to me? :)

I can Ctrl-TAB to LibreOffice, but it doesn't show and menu doesn't change in the case (on monitor 1). It probably changes on monitor 2, but I don't see it, either because it is disconnected or because of a glitch.

Comment: That's quite a change from the original question, I'll see if I can think of another solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag a window by any part of the bottom edge, so long as you're not triggering the resize arrows.

[image]

If you're really stuck, then add Zoom as a key command…

[image]

If this happens in one specific app, contact the developer. Windows shouldn't ever go offscreen entirely, or ever cross the menu bar.

If all this fails, close then re-open the Window - it ought to be forced back inside the screen.

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't have any corner of the window on screen 1. Creating shortcut and activating it has no effect: application remains on screen 2.

Comment: There was no mention of a screen 2. You need to ask the question you actually need the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

I have one old program that is still useful, but has not been updated in a long time. When it gets stuck I can't even grab enough as the previous answers recommend.

A very simple solution I've found is to temporarily hide the Menu bar. Go to System Preferences app → General and check Automatically hide and show the menu bar.

This will hide the Menu bar, which can be easily revealed by hovering the cursor towards top of the screen.

Now once the menu bar is hidden, carefully move the cursor just up to the app title bar, without touching the edge of the screen. Drag the app window to suitable location.

Once done, you can disable Menu bar autohide.